# Need help looping through a query result to update fields

Tags: sql, loops

Ok first the query I will be displaying is very rough looking. Pointers on how to optimize it would be great but that is not my main purpose right now I need something that works. I will post the query and the results

```
    SELECT u.[UserName]
      ,u.[LoweredUserName]
      ,m.[BarCode]
      ,m.[MemberID]
      ,d.[FirstName]
      ,d.[LastName]
  FROM [sqlmdstgbiz02].[WebDB].[dbo].[aspnet_Users] u,
  [mdsqlst].[CMS_PRODUCTION].[dbo].[memMember] me,
  [mdsqlst].[CMS_PRODUCTION].[dbo].[Demographics] d,
  [sqlmd05stg\sqlmd05stg].EntranceControl.dbo.MemberBarCodes m
  where
  (substring(u.UserName, len(u.UserName)-12,13) = m.Barcode or
  substring(u.UserName, len(u.UserName)-11,12)  = m.Barcode or
  substring(u.UserName, len(u.UserName)-10,11)  = m.Barcode or
  substring(u.UserName, len(u.UserName)-9,10)  = m.Barcode or
  substring(u.UserName, len(u.UserName)-8,9) = m.Barcode) and
  me.MemberID = m.MemberID and me.DemographicsID = d.DemographicsID
```

The results of the code are

```
UserName          BarCode        MemberID      FirstName   LastName
down120000008     120000008      8300100364005 TOUCH       DOWN
test120000009     120000009      8300100606009 KET TAG     TEST
abbott123567567   123567567      8300100635008 HENRY       ABBOTT
```

Now as you can see the UserName is simple the Lastname and the BarCode combined together. What I need to do is update the UserName with the LastName and MemberID but in a way that will allow me to update hundreds of UserName with one script. All of this information is on different servers so I know I have to do a Linked Server which the DBA is setting up right now. Any more information please ask.

Comment: Frankly, this is a horrible design. If you need to join to the barcode table, you shoudl be storing the barcode as a separate field inthe users table. You do not want to use OR or functions in a join if it can be avoided. And stop using implicit syntax, that is a very bad habit.

Comment: Sorry I am just trying to get this to work. I didn't design these tables at all I am new here and was just given this task and trying to do the best I can with what I was given. What implicit syntax are you referring to so I can correct myself

Comment: @cjohnson2136 - HLGEM is refering to the fact that you *link* the tables together in your `where` clause instead of using the `inner join` syntax

Comment: Oh ok so these two clauses should be part of an inner join me.MemberID = m.MemberID and me.DemographicsID = d.DemographicsID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is SQL Server, you can use [UPDATE FROM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to perform the update.

```
 BEGIN TRAN

 UPDATE u 
 SET    UserName = d.FirstName + m.MemberID
 OUTPUT INSERTED.*
 FROM   [sqlmdstgbiz02].[WebDB].[dbo].[aspnet_Users] u
        , [mdsqlst].[CMS_PRODUCTION].[dbo].[memMember] me
        , [mdsqlst].[CMS_PRODUCTION].[dbo].[Demographics] d
        , [sqlmd05stg\sqlmd05stg].EntranceControl.dbo.MemberBarCodes m
 WHERE  (substring(u.UserName, len(u.UserName)-12,13) = m.Barcode 
          or substring(u.UserName, len(u.UserName)-11,12)  = m.Barcode 
          or substring(u.UserName, len(u.UserName)-10,11)  = m.Barcode 
          or substring(u.UserName, len(u.UserName)-9,10)  = m.Barcode 
          or substring(u.UserName, len(u.UserName)-8,9) = m.Barcode
        ) 
        and me.MemberID = m.MemberID 
        and me.DemographicsID = d.DemographicsID

 ROLLBACK TRAN
```

**Edit**

As HLGEM correctly points out, you should replace the implicit syntax with proper INNER JOIN statements.

```
 BEGIN TRAN

 UPDATE u
 SET    UserName = d.FirstName + m.MemberID
 OUTPUT INSERTED.*
 FROM   [mdsqlst].[CMS_PRODUCTION].[dbo].[memMember] me
        INNER JOIN [mdsqlst].[CMS_PRODUCTION].[dbo].[Demographics] d ON d.DemographicsID = me.DemographicsID
        INNER JOIN [sqlmd05stg\sqlmd05stg].EntranceControl.dbo.MemberBarCodes m ON m.MemberID = me.MemberID
        INNER JOIN [sqlmdstgbiz02].[WebDB].[dbo].[aspnet_Users] u ON u.UserName LIKE '%' + m.Barcode

 ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: will that actually loop through all the results?

Comment: any performance suggestion because the query I posted above takes about 11 min to run?

Comment: @cjohnson2136 - I have added an OUTPUT statement placed the update in a rolled back transaction. Executing this statement allows you to *preview* what is going to change.

Comment: You could try replacing the entire or clause with `u.UserName LIKE '%' + m.Barcode`. But beware that that might lead to false positives (but so does your code as it is).

Comment: @HLGEM - I didn't use it per se, I merely repeated what OP posted to show how little needed to be changed. You are correct offcourse that I should have mentioned that this is an antipattern.

Comment: No it is not looping through the records, it is adjusting all of them at once as a set. You almost never want to loop through records that too is a SQL anti-patttern. If this takes 11 mintues, looping could take several hours.

Comment: wait what did I do wrong. I'm sorry I am not that great with advanced SQL scripts

Comment: @cjohnson2136 - you didn't do anything wrong per se but you are thinking procedural io set based. A good read on that would be [Thinking in Sets](http://sqlserverconsulting.blogspot.com/2009/12/thinking-in-sets.html)

Comment: @Lieven thanks I will give this a read over and hopefully improve my query.

Comment: @Lieven with u.UserName LIKE '%' + m.Barcode so it is only looking for the ending characters. Like if I did a LIKE on abbott123567567 could I tell it to only be like the last 9 digits?

Comment: @cjohnson2136 - not in its current form but you could replace `u.UserName LIKE '%' + m.Barcode` with `SUBTRING(u.UserName, LEN(u.Username)-9, 9)  LIKE '%' + m.Barcode`

Comment: My query is running much faster I just had to change the like to a = and it decrease the query time by 10 min. Checked it with the boss and he said all is good with it.

Comment: @cjohnson2136 - thank you for the update but by changing the LIKE to = you might be missing out results.

Comment: the only time i would miss results is if the keycode got padded and was not 9 digits. I checked with my boss and padding was never added so any key codes added could ONLY be 9 digits