# A Simple but complex SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very simple MS SQL table with the following data(with column name and datatype):

```
TableId     PersonName              Attribute           AttributeValue
(int)       (nvarchar 50)           (nvarchar 50)       (bit)
----------- ----------------------- ------------------- --------------
1           A                       IsHuman             1
2           A                       CanSpeak            1
3           A                       CanSee              1
4           A                       CanWalk             0
5           B                       IsHuman             1
6           B                       CanSpeak            1
7           B                       CanSee              0
8           B                       CanWalk             0
9           C                       IsHuman             0
10          C                       CanSpeak            1
11          C                       CanSee              1
12          C                       CanWalk             0
```

Now, What I need as a result is the unique PersonName that have both Attribute IsHuman and CanSpeak with AttributeValue = 1.

The expected result should be (Must not include C as this one has IsHuman = 0)

```
PersonName
------------
A
B
```

Please can any expert help me in writting a SQL Query for this.

Comment: @suresh you posted your answer here and i also format that question and its look ok then why you changed all that to this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT PersonName 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE (AttributeName = 'IsHuman' AND AttributeValue = 1) OR 
      (AttributeName = 'CanSpeak' AND AttributeValue = 1) 
GROUP BY PersonName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

**or**

```
SELECT PersonName 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE AttributeValue = 1 AND AttributeName IN ('IsHuman', 'CanSpeak') 
GROUP BY PersonName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: it should have the exact same execution plan as your original version but I find it a bit more readable. +1 btw on you solution.

Comment: Hi Dylan Smith, Thanks for prompt reply. Can we add more in where clause like "CanSee", "CanWalk" ect. according to the user selection. It may vary according to the selection.

Comment: @sureshjat: sounds like you need to look at relational operator [division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29), popularly known as ["the supplier who supplies all parts"](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/772076.htm), specifically [division with remainder](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

Comment: Sure, just add it to the IN clause and increase the number in the HAVING clause appropriately

Comment: Both solutions will work wrong if (for exapmle) there will be two records with AttributeName = 'IsHuman' and AttributeValue = 1

Comment: @Alex_L - only when they have *the same* PersonName. I think it is safe to assume that the combination `PersonName, AttributeName` is unique.

Comment: "I think it is safe to assume" -- I don't see why this is safe, the presence of `TableId` suggests otherwise.

Comment: @Lieven - Ok, but I wasn't not so sure.

Comment: @onedaywhen - I didn't notice that but you are right. OP might clarify on that but imo, a unique constraint *should* exist on those two fields.

Comment: If those fields aren't unique, then I'd do a nested select that groups by those fields, and applies the appropriate aggregate operator to the AttributeValue based on desired behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT PersonName 
  FROM MyTable 
 WHERE AttributeName = 'IsHuman' 
       AND AttributeValue = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT PersonName 
  FROM MyTable 
 WHERE AttributeName = 'CanSpeak' 
       AND AttributeValue = 1;
```

Obviously this approach doesn't 'scale' if the criteria can vary. It could be that the relational operator you require is [division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29), popularly known as ["the supplier who supplies all parts"](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/772076.htm), specifically [division with remainder](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT PersonName FROM MyTable 
WHERE PersonName IN 
(SELECT T1.PersonName FROM MyTable T1 WHERE T1.Attribute = 'IsHuman' and T1.AttributeValue='1')
AND (Attribute = 'CanSpeak' AND AttributeValue='1')
```

Comment: This won't work only because I have used wrong type of AttributeValue. I cannot see another problem. Explain it, please.

Comment: I missed the closing parentheses of your IN statement and read this as that the CanSpeak clause was ANDed with the IsHuman clause. I'll delete my comment and upvote this answer but you might consider reformatting the statement to make it obvious that the AND is NOT part of the IN statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
select personname from yourtablename where personname in ('a','b') group by personname
```

Comment: It gives the expected result ... :)

Comment: Hi Dylan Smith,
Can we add more in where clause like "CanSee", "CanWalk" ect. according to the user selection. It may varyy according to the selection.

Answer (score 0):

I think two inner joins may give you alright performance depending on indexing and table sizes.

```
SELECT t.PersonName FROM table t 
INNER JOIN table t2 ON t.PersonName=t2.PersonName AND t3.Attribute = 'IsHuman' AND t2.AttributeValue = 1 
INNER JOIN table t3 ON t2.PersonName=t3.PersonName AND t3.Attribute = 'CanSpeak' AND t3.AttributeValue = 1
```

or

```
SELECT t.PersonName FROM table t 
INNER JOIN table t2 ON t.PersonName=t2.PersonName
INNER JOIN table t3 ON  t2.PersonName=t3.PersonName
WHERE t2.Attribute = 'IsHuman' AND t2.AttributeValue = 1 AND t3.Attribute = 'CanSpeak' AND t3.AttributeValue = 1
```

This solution could be simplified significantly however should the properties IsHuman and CanSpeak were in separate tables with an linking ID table between them. Sounds like this table could possibly benefit from some normalization.

If you cant progress that, a view may assist in performance. I am at home without SQL installed so I cant verify any performance aspects.

Answer (score -1):

I actually use this as a screening question for interviews.  None of you people would get the job.

OK, maybe you would, but while the strategies you use might or might not work, they aren't generalizable and they miss a basic notion of relational algebra, to wit, aliasing.

The right answer (in the sense that it would make me more likely to employ you as well as the less importance senses that the RDMS's optimizer understands it and it can be extended to other, arbitrarily complex, cases) is

```
SELECT t1.PersonName 
  FROM MyTable t1, MyTable t2
 WHERE t2.AttributeName = 'CanSpeak' 
       AND t2.AttributeValue = 1
       AND t1.AttributeName = 'IsHuman' 
       AND t1.AttributeValue = 1
       AND t1.PersonName = t2.PersonName;
```

Comment: This statement contains an error, uses an antipattern and performs worse than the proposed solutions. You should dismiss anyone who proposes this <vbg> (not my downvote btw)

Comment: Can be extended by adding a new table expression per row of search criteria, which isn't practical. While I agree it can be extended to arbitrarily complex cases, it is not easy to achieve. The 'proper' way to do this is to use image relations. In SQL the best we can get is relational division. Remember that in **SQL**, the unit of work is the row (not the table): the way to extend in this case is add criteria rows to a divisor table and use use the same query each. Your proposal is essentially dynamic SQL.

Comment: BTW the relation rename operator you call an "alias" (and the SQL Standards calls a "correlation name") does not form part of any relational algebra that I am aware of. Sure, it is useful but not crucial enough for an algebra. Darwen's algebra includes attribute rename but not relation rename. Indeed, Darwen is specifically critical of the fact SQL forces one to unnecessarily apply a correlation name to a table. [Citation](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Importance-of-Column-Names.pdf): page 9, `TEETH_GNASHER`.

Comment: @Lieven -- your comment contains an irrelevancy, an unfalsifiable assertion, and an appeal to authority.

Comment: @onedaywhen -- if the search criteria were allowed to vary, then yes, you could not use this technique.  Assuming the criteria were solely a union of the cases, then division, as you mention in your comments on the OP, would be the right solution, but does any SQL implement division?  I gave up on calling it "correlation name" because so many RDBMS docs call it "alias", but "rename" is just misleading: it's a view on a table and I'm naming it, not renaming it.  Among SQL's many, many flaws is that sometimes it unnecessarily requires correlation names, but this is not one of those times.

Comment: "sometimes [SQL] unnecessarily requires correlation names, but this is not one of those times" -- arguably it is: the only reason the correlation names are required in your SQL code is to disambiguate the column names but SQL does not let you 'rename' the columns without also 'renaming' the table. For example, the Tutorial D translation of your SQL would be: `( MyTable JOIN ( MyTable RENAME { AttributeName AS v , AttributeName AS n } ) ) WHERE n = 'CanSpeak' AND v = 1 AND AttributeName = 'IsHuman' AND AttributeValue = 1`

Comment: @Malvolio - if you took offence, I apologize but let me clarify. The antipatern is in using old style joins. The performance statement is because this solution has more data to juggle with. One might reasonbly expect it to not outperform the other solutions. As for authority, that's easy, I have none.

Comment: @onedaywhen - that's an interesting way to look at it: you don't need to rename the table, you just need to rename every column in the table.  From that perspective, the renaming is only a convenience, but it's a heckofa convenience.

Comment: @Lieven -- I did take offense, but I take offense too easily, so don't worry about it.  Do you really thing that specifying the join type (which is I assume is what you mean by "new-style") will help the optimizer that much?

Comment: @Malvolio - the optimizer couldn't care less, but the reader does :). Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798217/need-help-looping-through-a-query-result-to-update-fields/7798313#7798313) where I answered with a slightly adjusted query, repeating OP's implicit syntax and got downvoted for it by someone with real authority.

Comment: @Lieven -- I keep going back and forth about whether the implicit join might be so *terse* as to cross the line into *cryptic* .  Right now, I'm thinking, no -- if only because so many people, including myself, grew up on implicit joins -- but am willing to be talked out of it.

Comment: @Lieven: I just upvoted that answer you linked to :) I don't believe the  person who downvoted you is an authority on SQL, SO is just a bubble... It is downvoting someone because they used a syntax style that is not to their taste. Calling it an "anitpattern" is nonsense, IMO. Now, I strongly believe that nulls should be avoided (and have plenty of evidence if you would care to listen) but the idea of me downvoting anyone who used nulls in their question/answer would be ridiculous.

Comment: @onedaywhen - A bubble? Maybe. My reputation does not reflect my knowledge, I just answer a lot but there are others mind you. Now if only [Martin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) where to chime in...

Comment: @Lieven: I was referring to [HLGEN](http://stackoverflow.com/users/9034/hlgem) who downvoted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798217/need-help-looping-through-a-query-result-to-update-fields/7798313#7798313) question. As regards my knowledge, I read around a lot and correspond with a few genuinely knowledgeable people, who are polite and kind and enough to indulge me (none of whom get worked up about old style inner joins). I guess even the SO SQL-antipattern police are nice people in real life ;)

Comment: @onedaywhen - I loved `who are polite and ...`  :)

Comment: @Lieven: I don't know *what* you mean ;)